# Align SVG and span in a list element

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to align a span to a svg image, but I'm struggling. Code and Codepen should be self-explaining.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <svg>*SVG-CODE*</svg><span>Align me</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

li {
  background: blue;
}

svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  alignment-baseline: central;
}

span {
  background: red;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

Full code: http://codepen.io/andreash/pen/zvwZjv

Comment: Are you saying you want the span to be vertically centered like the SVG square is? If so you can add `vertical-align:middle` to the span as you have with the SVG.

Answer (score 3):

ahh.. my slow brain today. I need vertical-align: middle to both svg and span. thanks @AndyFurniss